# How to get artefacts from another pipeline build

Tags: azure-pipelines

I want to separate out my build and deployment stages from an Azure Devops pipeline. I'm looking at [Pipeline triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops) and that works great, but how to I pick up the artefacts (web deploy package) generated by the previous pipeline, so I can deploy it in the current pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Artefacts can be downloaded from other pipelines using the normal [Download Artefacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#download-artifacts) by specifying the [`pipeline` input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) (and maybe combining it with `runVersion` and `runBranch` constraints).